# How remove vertical spacing between li css

Tags: css, margin, spacing

I have this html code and style "this is just an example":

```
<div id="mn" style="margin-top:200px;">
                <div class="first">1</div>
                <div class="second">2</div>
                <div class="third">3</div>
                <div class="fourth">4</div>
            </div>

<style type="text/css">
        #mn, #mn div { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
        #mn div { width:350px; margin:5px; /* float:left Comment */ }
        div.first { height:5px; background-color:Red; }
        div.second { height:120px; background-color:#999 }
        div.third { height:50px; background-color:Yellow }
        div.fourth { height:180px; background-color:#ccc }
    </style>
```

The problem is, the element on left "the yellow and red ones" have a big space or bottom margin between these.
I need delete this big margin or spacing and use just 5px in all element.

I created a script with jquery that take the List and move them to a divs, something like that:

```
<div id="mn_left"></div>
            <div id="mn_right"></div>
            <div id="mn" style="margin-top:200px;">
                <div class="first">1</div>
                <div class="second">2</div>
                <div class="third">3</div>
                <div class="fourth">4</div>
            </div>

$(document).ready(function () {            
            $("div", "#mn").each(function (e, value) {
                if ($("#mn_left").height() <= $("#mn_right").height()) {
                    $("#mn_left").append(value.outerHTML);
                }
                else {
                    $("#mn_right").append(value.outerHTML);
                }
            });
        });
```

The script works fine, but I want to do it without scripts.

**Edit...**
I mistook, I changed the li by divs... But it's exactly the same. The Html Looks Like that:

http://postimg.org/image/dh6dwdjc1/

What I really want is this

http://postimg.org/image/otnkrwhep/

Comment: In your example I don't see a list, just `div`s. Is your intent to code with `ul` and `li` (if it's a list, then you should).

Comment: The reason for this margin is that the yellow and red div are not the same height as the divs on the right. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: From your edit I would have to ask why would not just restructure your markup?  Is there a reason you cannot restructure?  Create 2 DIVs, the left containing items 1, 3, 4 and the right containing item 2.

Answer (score 0):

First off, here is your code properly set up using list markup, since you said it's a list:

HTML:

```
<ul id="mn">
    <li class="first">1</li>
    <li class="second">2</li>
    <li class="third">3</li>
    <li class="fourth">4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#mn {padding:0; margin:0;}
#mn, #mn li { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
#mn li { width:350px; margin:5px; }
li.first { height:5px; background-color:Red; }
li.second { height:120px; background-color:#999 }
li.third { height:50px; background-color:Yellow }
li.fourth { height:180px; background-color:#ccc }
```

- ([JSFiddle Link 1](http://jsfiddle.net/RVDJY/))

Then, remove the `margin` from `#mn li`:

```
#mn li { width:350px; /* margin:5px; */ }
```

- ([JSFiddle Link2](http://jsfiddle.net/RVDJY/1/) )

You'll see the list items are flush now, except the first item, where the line height is taller than the item height. To fix that first one, give the list items an `overflow:hidden;` and change the `display` from `inline-block` to just `block`.

```
#mn, #mn li { display:block; vertical-align:middle; }
#mn li { width:350px; overflow: hidden;}
```

- ([JSFiddle Link 3](http://jsfiddle.net/RVDJY/2/))

That should be it for you, unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: Hello, I mistook, I changed the li by divs... But it's exactly the same. The Html Looks Like that:

http://postimg.org/image/dh6dwdjc1/

What I really want is this

http://postimg.org/image/otnkrwhep/

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood you. I don't think you're going to find a general solution to that without using Javascript. CSS can't move things based on the heights of other things. Unless your element heights are fixed... are they fixed? Or do you need to have it work based on the contents changing?

Comment: Yes, the height is dinamyc. Then, I have to use javascript... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  Using floats instead of absolute positioning.

```css
#mn {width: 720px;}
#mn div { width:350px; float:left; margin:5px; }
#mn div.second {float:right;}
div.first { height:5px; background-color:Red; }
div.second { height:120px; background-color:#999; }
div.third { height:50px; background-color:Yellow }
div.fourth { height:180px; background-color:#ccc }
```

- Floated all to left.
- Added a new CSS rule for the containing `div` of
  `#mn`.  The width is equal to the width of each child div plus it's
  margins, so `( 5px + 350px + 5px ) = ( 360px x 2 ) = 720px`.
- Added new CSS declaration for the second div.

Comment: Hi... Thanks, but in your example de element are not floating, I want two items by row...

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you're trying to do...

One way to do that is to create a class for the items that will be in the second colum:

```
#mn .col2 { position: absolute; left: 355px; top:0; margin-top: 0;}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RVDJY/4/). (PS, You need `#mn{position:relative;}` for the above to work.)

The problem with this is that if you have more than one item in the second column, you'll have to give the second (and third, fourth, etc) items a custom `top` position so that they line up properly.

This seems like a perfect place to use Javascript instead of CSS. And that's coming from a proponent of "always use CSS whenever you can!"

Comment: Thanks again, this is not functional for me because as I said that was just an example. The items are loaded dynamically and may be more. If don't have a solutions I will have to use the script.